# Vuejs computed properties with array

Tags: vue.js

I have the following component:

```
data() {
   return {
     cars: []
   }
}
```

And I need to set a color to each car:

```
<div v-for="car in cars">
   <span :color="setColor"></span>
</div>
```

How can I set a specific color to each car using a computed property ?
I have to use a specific logic inside a function:

```
if (car == 'a') {
  return 'black'
} else if (car == 'b') {
  return 'blue'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the car objects to have something like a `color` property on them. If this is true, you don't need computed property, and you can use the following snippet:

```
<div v-for="car in cars">
   <span :color="car.color"></span>
</div>
```

However, it seems your code has more problems than just what you described. `span` is a native HTML element, and as far as I know, it has no `color` attribute, like your code seems to assume.

Also, your `cars` data property is an empty array, so looping throught it won't work very well. You would need something like this to make the previous snippet work (if we forget the `span` problem):

```
data() {
   return {
     cars: [
       { color: 'red' },
       { color: 'blue' }
     ]
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You don't need to use a computed property for that, you could rather use a method:

```
<div v-for="car in cars">
   <span :color="getColor(car)"></span>
</div>
```

```
methods: {
  getColor(car) {
    if (car === 'a') {
      return 'black'
    } else if (car === 'b') {
      return 'blue'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just updated my question. I can't use a color property from car.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a computed property but a method, since it needs to receive an argument (the `car` variable, that is). Some tips:

- Since it's technically a gets a value, perhaps `getColor()` will be a more appropriate name
- Always use `===` when appropriate

```
methods: {
  getColor(car) {
    if (car === 'a') {
      return 'black'
    } else if (car === 'b') {
      return 'blue'
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in the template as such:

```
<div v-for="car in cars">
   <span :color="getColor(car)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't pass param into `computed` function, you need to get all array of colors or use `method` instead.

Solution1: Get list of all colors.

```
<div v-for="(car, index) in cars">
   <span :color="carColors[index]"></span>
</div>
...
computed: {
  carColors() {
    return this.cars.map(car => car === 'a' ? 'black' : 'blue');
  }
}
```

Solution2: Use method instead as @Terry' answer.

```
<div v-for="car in cars">
   <span :color="getColor(car)"></span>
</div>
...
methods: {
  getColor(car) {
    if (car === 'a') {
      return 'black'
    } else if (car === 'b') {
      return 'blue'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a method, not a computed variable since it gets a parameter (car's id or so)

Create a method named `setColor`

```
setColor(car) {
     if (car === 'a') {
        return 'black'
      } else if (car === 'b') {
     return 'blue'
 }
},
```